# NPM -g update gives me many WARN dependency errors

Tags: npm

Should I delete my node modules folder and reinstall everything again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that following [David Walsh's way of updating Node](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs) has resolved my problem.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

[image]